# How to use the parentView.template in N nested children in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

here is what I'm trying to do:

I want to create a tree widget in emberjs that will look like:

```
    {{view UI.TreeView content="App.rootNode"}}
        {{name}} //-> content of each node, it could be <img src="{{icon}}" /> {{name}}
    {{/view}}
```

The problem I'm facing is how to use the inner template in my itemViewClass.

Here is what I came up with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/YJ7zM/13/

Relevant line:

```
   template: Em.Handlebars.compile("{{name}} {{view UI.TreeChildrenView contentBinding=\"children\"}}")
```

That's the line I don't like and would like to replace with something more like:

```
   templateBinding: "parentView.template"
```

The problem is that "parentView" will only work for the first level of the tree, for the other ones it would be "parentView.parentView.template" and so go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always define the template externally and use `templateName`...

http://jsfiddle.net/YJ7zM/14/

**edit**

Revised to address first comment. http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/mgCva/

Comment: That would require a decoupled definition of templates when creating my tree. I want to AVOID that.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. See my revised answer. Other than convenience I don't see why decoupling the definition of your templates is a bad thing here... I'd be curious to hear why exactly you think this route is a better way to go.

Comment: Thank you, Roy. Well, I think it's way cleaner and more intuitive to have them together since they are relate to each other. And for consistence, the other widgets I created work the same way.